# I can`t startx anymore in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

if possible I want help with this strange error that happened.

I was configuring my awesome window manager, then I restarted it to apply the configurations that I made and my PC freezed. I rebooted and suddenly I couldn't startx anymore. For my luck I found an old cd of my linux mint and booted with it. The problem is, I did a backup of the rc.lua, and even after restoring it, I can't startx, so I think that the problem is something else. The Xorg.0.log is empty, I don't know why, and I already resintalled Xorg 1.13 and the catalyst drivers, and can't make it work yet. Just for note, I installed other wm`s too, Openbox and dwm, and the same thing happens

Here some infos.

My `xinitrc` is pretty simple

```
!/bin/bash
~/.xinitrc

xsetroot -DMZ left_ptr

setxkbmap jp

exec awesome
```

`Xorg 1.13` and the `AMD` proprietary drivers, I already tried with the mesa drivers, and doesn't work too.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for you attention reading it.(Sorry if I'm doing anything wrong, my first time posting here)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are putting yourself in an infinite initialisation loop.  You are calling xinitrc from xinitrc.

Try commenting out the ~/.xinitrc line:

> #~/.xinitrc

After that, it should work, but pay a visit [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) to see the Arch way of setting up .xinitrc